# URL white list and black list in JavaScript with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, url, whitelist, blacklist

I have two arrays in javascript one for my whitelist and one for the blacklist. I am using the to see if a url should be allowed to be visisted. The arrays are filled with regex patterns for matching urls. For simplicity I will use these arrays as an example:

```
var white = [
    /https?:\/\/github\.com/,
    /https?:\/\/github\.com\/username\/repo/
];

var black = [
    /https?:\/\/github.com\/username/
];
```

My function is currently looking like this:

```
function can_visit(url){
    //return true if url not in white or black, or white rule is most specific.
    //return false if black rule is most specific.
}
```

This should return true for `github.com` and `github.com/user/repo`, but return false `github.com/user/`. Rules in one list can override rules in the other as long as they are more specific.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, you are basically asking us to write your routine. To get you started: use `Array.prototype.forEach` together with `RegExp` and `RegExp.prototype.test()`. Then keep a white/black list score. If the URL scores more on the white list, allow, if not deny.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the "get your coding assignments done for free" platform. Ask a question. *"Can you write this for me?"* is not a question.